# how to call def from another .py in different folder

Tags: python

I have following structure:
utils_dir has generator.py file which has 3 defs.

I have test.py in inline_dir. And I am trying to use defs from generator.py in test.py.

inline_dir and utils_dir are in different folders.
How can I achieve it to use defs?

Tried with creating `_init_.py` and then calling `import generator`. - Not worked.
Tried `from utils import generator` - Not worked

`Dir structure`

`Support_dir
├── dir_A
│   ├── dir_aa
│   └──----- main.py   [Want to use a and b from generator.py]
└── utils
    |
    └── generator.py
             |
             |___ def a
             |___ def b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to execute a .py file in a subdirectory.

Assuming the following directory structure:

```
.
├── inline
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── generator.py
```

And your `main.py` containing a simple import like (the function `a()` being defined in `generator.py`):

```
from utils.generator import a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a()
```

And `generator.py` would look something like this:

```
def a():
    print "hi there"
```

You won't be able to run your program using `python inline/main.py` because this will set the module search path to `inline/`

If you want to execute a file in a subdirectory while importing from your project-level, you could do the following:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python inline/main.py
```

**UPDATE:** Added example `generator.py`

Comment: I am trying to use def from generator.py file.  let me try above

Comment: I added the function definition for ```generator.py``` above

Comment: looks like you're just missing an ```__init__.py``` file in your ```utils/``` directory

Comment: I just added `__init__.py` in utils and `dir_aa`. still not working

Comment: after adding the ```__init__.py``` file, try going into the ```Support_dir``` and running ```PYTHONPATH=. python dir_A /dir_aa/main.py```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122930/discussion-between-jann-and-beginner-yaml-user).

Answer (score 3):

This is a kind of a python path problem. When you import, python will search current directory and default system path directory. Since utils_dir is not your current work directory (when import, you work in inline_dir), nor in default python search system path, that is why the import not work.

A simple way to solve is

a). First make utils_dir as python package: simply add **init**.py in the directory.

b). Then, add path of parent folder of utils_dir to PYTHONPATH environment variable.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/parent_of_utils_dir:$PYTHONPATH
```

You can add this line into your .bashrc to make it available all the time.

c). In your test.py, import the function

```
from utils import generator
```

or

```
import utils.generator
```

A more python development way is to use setuptools, and write python script setup.py, which will solve dependency problem. And then you can use

```
python setup.py develop
```

to use in develop mode.

Check more python package development guide at https://packaging.python.org/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Upvote for the link to documentation - Thank you! Google has not been forthcoming with this despite efforts on my part :D