# How to import functions from a different folder in python?

Tags: python

Q1: So let's say I have 2 folders and some files in them like this:

```
root
├── Folder
│   └── file.py
└── Folder1
    └── file2.py
```

Let's say that I have a function in `file.py` named `function()` and I want to use it in `file2.py`. How can I make this happen?

Q2: If `file.py` contains 5 functions, and I want to use them at any time in `file2.py`. How do I do that? Is it any different to the answer in the previous question?

```
function()
function1()
function2()
function3()
function4()
```

I've tried something with init.py and PYTHONPATH and it didn't work so I've decided to start from the begining.

Comment: Two things: 

1) Are your two folders located within the same directory?

2) What have you tried with`__init__.py`? could you provide an example?

Comment: 1) No, they are in a seperate directory, sorry forgot to provide that info.
2) I've deleted everything I've done but tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397720/how-to-call-def-from-another-py-in-different-folder/39398291#39398291

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
#You write this code in file2.py
#This imports the whole file2

import numpy as np
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "../Folder")
import file.py as U

def main():
  s = U.log_sig(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main
```

Or if you like to import only `function()` from `file.py` then:

```
from file import function

s = function()
```